# What would be an apt technical term for the fear of eating cat food?

Tags: neologisms

If there were a technical term for the condition in which a person is irrationally and intensely afraid of inadvertently eating cat food, what would that term be?

[image: a pink pet bowl piled high with glistening chunks of cat food]

Comment: Do we really need such a large picture to illustrate a well-known expression? I also think that image does a disservice to the question, if *anyone* was served a similar pet's dish I think it would be *perfectly* rational to be disgusted, and want to avoid eating it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am confused. Oh, wait, you mean "cat food" is a well-known. I thought you meant "eating cat food" is a well-known expression. I wondered what it meant! Americans constantly surprise me (two people separated by a common language etc). Of course, you will now tell me neither ted strauss nor you are American. :(

Comment: @almagest  I'm not American, (I don't know about Ted Straus, but I think he is) and yes, I did mean "cat food".

Comment: I'm suddenly feeling hungry.

Comment: Oddly enough, "eating cat food" *is* as well-known expression, and refers to poverty among senior citizens (mostly metaphorical, but by extension from a literal practice). In that case, the technical term to use might be more closely aligned with financial insecurity than with the substance itself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA the reason behind the large picture is to illustrate the sense of dread and compulsive imagery associated with phobic tendencies. But I will gladly remove it if your comment receives 3 upvotes. Incidentally, what makes you think I am American? Is it my name, my avatar, or my question about cat food?

Comment: Apologies, you are from Montreal, Canada, it says so on your profile. As for my comment, perhaps you ought to reflect why your question hasn't been voted up. :)

Comment: +1 for Q,+1 for C. I have learnt several things from all this brouhaha :)

Comment: Generally it's _eating pet food_ or _eating dog food_, but _eating cat food_ does the same job of evoking poor old folks with no resources. If that's not the sense intended, then it's a very strange phobia that distinguishes between cat food and other pet food, or for that matter many other substances unpleasant to eat. Maybe a primal scene involving a cat somewhere in the woodpile?

Answer (score 5):

*Fancyfeastophobia* (obviously).

Comment: .........hahahahaha! :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, from [The Phobia List](http://phobialist.com), we get...

> Cats- Aclurophobia, Ailurophobia, Elurophobia, Felinophobia, Galeophobia, or Gatophobia.
>
> Food- Cibophobia
>
> Eating or swallowing- Phagophobia

so, I'd wager it's something like...*Felicibophagophobia*?

Comment: felici- would be happiness, and it's Latin, while phobia is greek; and there is, as you noted, already a greek word for fear of cats: ailurophobia. Maybe *ailurocibophagophobia*?

Comment: @medica I think it's meant to be: feli.cibo.phago.phobia.

Comment: Right, but that would be putting a latin prefix among the Greek. The Greek already has a word for cat-fear.

Comment: Oh, I did not notice the Greek/Latin word origins. I just thought felicibo flowed better than ailurocibo. Perhaps medica is correct.